# Scheduled Jobs in Spring using Akka

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, akka, batch-processing

I am trying to determine the best way to implement handling long running batch jobs in Spring MVC. I come across Akka in my searching as a non blocking framework for aync processing, which is preferred because I don't want the batch processing to eat up all the threads from the thread pool.

Essentially what I will be doing is have a job that needs to run on some set schedule that will go out and call various web services, process the data, and persist it.

I have seen some code example with using it with Spring, but I've never seen it used with a CRON type scheduler. It always seems to be using a fixed time period.

I'm not sure if this is even the best approach to handling large scale batch processing within Spring. Any suggestions or links to good Akka Spring resources are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) and [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) projects. The first one allows you configure chains of services using EIP. We used it in or project to fetch files from FTP, deserialize and process them, import into DB, send emails if required etc. - all by schedule. The second one is more straightforward and basically provides a framework to work on rows of data. Both are configurable with Quartz and integrate into Spring MVC project nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also found the following and wondering about this as well http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html? Question about Spring batch and Integration, can they be done Asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, they are both using configured or default SceduledExecutor, so of course they are executing in a background thread.

Comment: Cool thanks. This looks like a better option for what I am trying to do. Akka seems complex for what I am trying to do. Akka seems more useful for real time processing than bath jobs.